# Can we comment for a more specific answer to our questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

First of all: I hope the title is not entirely confusing, if it is, I'm open to suggestions.

The thing is, I asked a question and someone gave an answer that I sort of liked BUT the answer only was like:

```
You can do something like what you are trying to do.
Here is a very cool link that you can follow: somelink

Some mild explanation about the link (a paragraph or so) ...
```

The link actually digs really deep into what I'm trying to do, so it answered the question I had BUT I sort of feel like I should not mark it as the "accepted answer" because the answer is to mainstream, sometimes less is more but I would like her/him to give a little example and I'm wondering if I can comment on his answer something like:

```
If you could give a small working example I will mark it as answer.
```

Is it allowed to tell the one who answered that I WILL mark it as accepted if they do a little more.

OR, should I just mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is okay to ask for a more detailed explanation (or to summarize the article), especially since we discourage link-only answers (the link can rot, making the answer useless).

No need to promise the checkmark. Asking the user to flesh out their answer will garner them more upvotes naturally anyways -- you don't need to provide the motivation.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation?.. trolling! No, but really, entirely what I wanted to know, thanks!